# Is there any IDE which offers Auto Complete Features for rospy library?

Tags: ros, ide

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi.

I want to know whether Eclipse or any other IDE offers autocomplete features for rospy library. For example if we write "rospy." the the IDE should automatically suggest the different functions that we can use.

Does any IDE offer this feature?

Kindly, help me.

Thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/192169/is-there-any-ide-which-offers-auto-complete-features-for-rospy-library?/) by [ish45](https://answers.ros.org/users/20021/ish45/) on ROS Answers with karma: 151 on 2014-09-08

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jarvisschultz](https://answers.ros.org/users/1272/jarvisschultz/) on 2014-09-08**:
Lately, I've been having great success using [jedi](http://tkf.github.io/emacs-jedi/latest/) for all Python completions, including rospy, in emacs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

With a little bit of setup, which is described [here](http://wiki.ros.org/IDEs), Eclipse can do this very well.

---

Originally posted by [Airuno2L](https://answers.ros.org/users/458/airuno2l/) with karma: 3460 on 2014-09-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ish45](https://answers.ros.org/users/20021/ish45/) on 2014-09-09**:
Thanks. I have tried to do from this tutorial, but I am still unable to get auto completion and other features. Is it possible for you to help me in any way??

**Comment by [Airuno2L](https://answers.ros.org/users/458/airuno2l/) on 2014-09-10**:
Are you receiving any errors throughout the process? Or did you go through the steps without problem and it is just not working?

**Comment by [ish45](https://answers.ros.org/users/20021/ish45/) on 2014-09-10**:
I completed all the steps and also imported the project into eclipse and also added the Environment Variables as mentioned above. But, when do coding and write "import rospy" and try to run it says that rospy module not found.
Could you suggest what could be the possible solution?

**Comment by [Airuno2L](https://answers.ros.org/users/458/airuno2l/) on 2014-09-10**:
Are you starting eclipse by clicking on the icon, or launching it from the command line? If starting from the icon, try launching from command line. I'm assuming you've configured your ROS environment the way described [here](http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Tutorials/InstallingandConfiguringROSEnvironment).

**Comment by [Airuno2L](https://answers.ros.org/users/458/airuno2l/) on 2014-09-10**:
And that you have `source /opt/ros/hydro/setup.bash` in your /.bashrc

**Comment by [ish45](https://answers.ros.org/users/20021/ish45/) on 2014-09-10**:
Yes, I have tried launching it both from command line and from the icon. I have also configured my ros environment. But still it is not able to resolve the imports. Thanks for the help. Would Emacs be better option ?

**Comment by [ish45](https://answers.ros.org/users/20021/ish45/) on 2014-09-11**:
Thanks. It is working now. I changed the workspace of eclipse to be the catkin workspace and followed the tutorial here [http://u.cs.biu.ac.il/~yehoshr1/89-685/ROSLesson2.pptx](http://u.cs.biu.ac.il/%7Eyehoshr1/89-685/ROSLesson2.pptx) which is an excellent tutorial and solved my problem. Thanks to all.

**Comment by [Airuno2L](https://answers.ros.org/users/458/airuno2l/) on 2014-09-11**:
Excellent find. Glad you got it up and running.

**Comment by [Airuno2L](https://answers.ros.org/users/458/airuno2l/) on 2014-09-11**:
I think you can change your comment to answer and select it as the correct answer so this thread doesn't remain open.